# Do I use "I" or "me" in a compound subject?

Tags: grammar

I want to know the correct form:

> He and I will go there
>   or
>   He and me will go there.

Which is correct?

Comment: The "correct" form is *"He and I will go"*. Probably no-one would say *"He and me will go"*, but in casual speech *"Me and him will go"* would be perfectly common (even more common with an actual proper noun such as *"Me and John will go"*).

Comment: *Grammatically* you can't say it because *"Me will go"* isn't valid (it's got an *object pronoun* where a *subject pronoun* is required: *"**I** will go"*). But in casual speech many people do in fact say things like *"Me and Jane are friends"* (or *"Jane and me are friends"*). It's just that *idiomatically* we don't tend to extend that "incorrect use of object pronoun" into every possible context, so, for example, *"Them and him and me will go"* is extremelky unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

It's supposed to be:

> He and I will go there

English word order is "subject-verb-object" and in English, word order typically wins out over anything else.  Typically what precedes the verb in a sentence is the subject, so subject pronouns will be expected and mistakes will probably be interpreted as that.

> Me and John will go to the store

This is very common, but wrong (don't use this in formal speech or an educated context).  "Me" is understood not to be an object pronoun purely based on the fact that it's the first word in the sentence, where the reader/listener expects the subject of the verb.  It also helps that object expressions in English are usually preceded by a preposition, such as "to" or "by" - since this isn't here, it's another cue that we mean "me" as "I".

> John and me will go to the store

You may hear this too.

> He and me will go to the store

This is uncommon, at least in my experience, probably not because of any grammatical rule, but the fact that "he and me" rhyming sounds jarring.  If you aren't listening too closely, you might think the speaker is saying "he and he" or "me and me", which doesn't make sense, and it may make the listener question if he/she heard that right.

> Him and me will go to the store

You'll hear this wrong thing quite a bit, though.

And you might even hear someone not so good with English say something like this

> Him and I will go to the store.

thinking it sounds right, when it really doesn't.

But again, because of English's sensitivity to word order, most people will know what you mean if you say any of the above.

Comment: Just to add for the original poster that the use of 'You and me' is quite common as a subject phrase (although still considered *ungrammatical*), for example [in this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTbBvPoxUkk).

Answer (score -2):

"Me and George went to the show."
"Me and George" - A Compound Subject.

"Me went to the show." - A Simple Subject